# React Router, nesting routes after the params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So, I currently have the following as part of my url map for react.

```
<Route path="dog" component={DogWrapper}>
    <Route path=":id" component={DogDetails}/>
    <Route path=":id/genealogy" component={Genealogy}/>
</Route>
```

But I'm never hitting the Genealogy component. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is with ordering. React-router works on precedence so it will always take the :id route first. Move the `geneaolgy` route up and you should be all set.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteMatching.md#precedence

Comment: Thanks. Thought that might be the issue but couldn't find any proof for it in the docs.